# Children's book about a child that falls into a puddle and travels through a dark, twisted realm

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

In the 1990s, when I was a child living in England (UK), I had an illustrated story book that my mother had bought me which was about a young child who falls into a puddle on a rainy day. When the child is inside the puddle, they are travelling through a 'twisted' reality where shadowy creatures (possibly made of dark water?) are existing in an 'alternative' reality. They were possibly accompanied by a parent on their journey, although I could be wrong about that. I seem to remember that the child makes their way back to the 'normal' world by the end of the story.

Can anybody help me find the name or any information about this book?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember anything about what the cover of the book looked like, or any distinguishing features of the artwork?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Jeremy and the Puddle](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12340779-jeremy-and-the-puddle) by Christopher Hobbs? It was published in 1990, and involves a child falling into a puddle (without his mother) and entering the world of Reflections. He does make his way back home safely.

> Jeremy is an awful child. He finds a puddle, jumps into the middle and disappears. He finds himself in the watery world of Reflections ruled by the Emperor of Mirrors. After many adventures and a confrontation with the Emperor, Jeremy finds his way back, determined never to jump into puddles again.

[image: Cover for the illustrated children's book: Jeremy and the Puddle.]

Comment: That's it! Thank you, I've just ordered a used copy, I'm looking forward to reading it again. I had forgotten how the trees had faces on the cover, a nice detail.